# Does webkit crawler need to use squid proxy?

Tags: python, webkit, web-crawler, squid

I am writing a crawler using webkit, does webkit cache stuffs? Do I need to use squid as a proxy for my webkit based crawler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `QWebKit`? PyQt/PySide doesn't use disk cache by default. You have to set a `QNetworkDiskCache` object to `QNetworkManager` to enable caching.

See the source code of [`webkit.py`](http://code.google.com/p/webscraping/source/browse/webkit.py) module in [webscraping](http://code.google.com/p/webscraping/) library, it shows how to enable caching in QWebkit.